# Placing content directly into <li> tag

Tags: html

I am confused about if this snippet is semantically right:

```
<ul>
   <li>Winter</li>
   <li>Summer</li>
</ul>
```

I do know that `<li>` tag can contain any tag, both block and inline, but on the example above content is placed directly on the `<li>` with no other tag refered to what type of content it is.

**Is the example above correct?**

Or it is neccesary (or better procedure) to ensure that every content listed has its own tag, in order to ensure its semantic meaning? For example:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <p>Winter</p>
   </li>
   <li>
       <p>Summer</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's semantically correct because it's just a text node inside a list, which is perfectly valid. Just doesn't have any special meaning in html

Comment: you could better use the `<br>` tag behind the text. It's just 1 tag instead of the `p` tag, but the list elements are correctly used. Or you could css it by adding an id or class to the list element.

Comment: @KingReload I'm not sure that I agree with you, if it's a list, it's a list :)

Comment: @Luke true a list is a list xD better to exclude any html tags

Comment: Ask yourself the question: is "Winter" a paragraph?

Comment: King Reload: Why a list can contain HTML? You can list `<div>` or `webcomponent` if you want.
@MrLister : you have the best reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the code is correct, it is simply text that will be rendered between the `<li>` elements, there is nothing wrong with this.  You would only need to specify more tags around it to better describe the document content *should it be required*.

Don't go adding tags just for the sake of it. Your HTML should, however, validate correctly.  As it currently stands, the text is perfectly described as a list item and can be interpreted as such.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally depend on your content and type of content. See the below link, its having the almost same discussion:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/semanticaly-correct-span-tags-inside-li-tags/5585/3

Sometime you might have content which is needed to be highlighted, and sometime it all about just showing simple textual information. Always figure out the priority.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Please copy related information from your link to form a proper answer or make this a comment.

Answer (score -1):

`p` tag are better to use to inform user about a text content (paragraph) but not mandatory.

Example: 
You can put simple world (as Summer or Winter) considered by HTML as text

```
  <ul>
     <li> Summer</li>
     <li> Winter</li>  
  </ul>
```

Or maybe you want to list paragraph ?

```
  <ul>
     <li> <p>Lorium IpsumLorium IpsumLorium Ipsum</p></li>
     <li> <p>Lorium IpsumLorium Ipsum</p></li>  
  </ul>
```

Other case: navigation menu

```
<nav> 
  <img src="logo.png" />
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>  
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your first example is invalid HTML. Also, a `<p>` *element* does not inform the *user* of anything. Only the browser is aware of that.

Comment: @Rob Humm, i was wondering about that on writing it but wasn't sure. I update my answer to be correct

Comment: Your first example is still invalid. A `<p>` element cannot contain a list.